# Nomad client mode ask for consul. Can I ignore this?

Tags: consul, nomad

Nomad client mode ask for consul.

- Can I ignore this or I might deploy consul ?
- Is it necessary?

  nomad-client_1  |
  2017/02/12 08:26:01.008267 [ERR] 
  client.consul: error reaping services in consul: Get http://127.0.0.1:8500/v1/agent/services: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8500: getsockopt: connection refused

Answer (score 0):

Consul is not required. From the docs (https://www.nomadproject.io/docs/agent/configuration/consul.html):
"To put it another way: if you have a Consul agent running on the same host as the Nomad agent with the default configuration, Nomad will automatically connect and configure with Consul."